# (javascript) local storage value index

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexof

I set the data to a key called 'todo' in Local Storage.

The structure is like this.

```
key: todo
value : [{"text":"text1","idx":1},
        {"text":"text2","idx":2},
        {"text":"text4","idx":4}]
```

How to find the index of an object with idx = "4"?

For example, an object with idx = 1 has an index of 0.

```
key: todo
value : [{"text":"text1","idx":1} => index: 0
        {"text":"text2","idx":2} => index: 1
        {"text":"text4","idx":4}] => index: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've already parsed the JSON string from local storage (if not you can use `JSON.parse()`), you can use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of an object with a given id:

```js
const arr = [{
  "text": "text1",
  "idx": 1
}, {
  "text": "text2",
  "idx": 2
}, {
  "text": "text4",
  "idx": 4
}];

const search = 4;
const res = arr.findIndex(({idx}) => idx === search); // find index of object where idx is equal to search (4)
console.log(res); // 2
```

Comment: The value of search can be 1, 2, or 4.
When `index 1 ({"text": "text2", "idx": 2})` is deleted, the index value of the `{"text": "text2", "idx": 2}` object must be found. 
For example, before index1 is cleared, the index of `{"text": "text2", "idx": 2}` is 2. But after it's cleared, the index is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`todo.findIndex(elem => elem.idx === 4 )`

Comment: The value of search can be 1, 2, or 4.
When `index 1 ({"text": "text2", "idx": 2})` is deleted, the index value of the `{"text": "text2", "idx": 2}` object must be found. 
For example, before index1 is cleared, the index of `{"text": "text2", "idx": 2}` is 2. But after it's cleared, the index is 1.